Splitting lines and getting the lengths in QGIS
I am new to QGIS. I need to split my vegetation line (2.19km length) into segments based on the erosion and accretion and want to get the length of those segments. I was able to split the vegetation line but, in the attribute table, the length of all segments has the length of the veg ling (2.19km). The segment lengths must be obviously less than 2,19km.

An other possibility is to use a virtual field in the attribute table, which can be created with the field calculator with the $lengthfunction. A virtual field will be updated automatically: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-a-virtual-field

Update your length field with the $length function.
https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#length
